# Finding the largest value among the properties of an object

Tags: string, function, object, replace, key-value

I have following task

Write a `function findBestEmployee (employees)` that takes an employee object and returns the name of the most productive one (who completed the most tasks). Employees and the number of completed tasks are contained as object properties in the format `"name": "number of tasks"`.

I below code it's showing me an error :

> The function is expected to return an empty string for an empty object. Can someone please help me.

```js
const findBestEmployee = function (employees) {
    'use strict';
  
    let max = 0;
    let bestEmployee;

    for (const employee in employees) {
        const numberOfTasks = employees[employee];
        if (numberOfTasks > max) {
            max = numberOfTasks;
            bestEmployee = employee;
        }
    }

    return bestEmployee;
};

const developers = {
    ann: 29,
    david: 35,
    helen: 1,
    lorence: 99,
};
 
//console.log(findBestEmployee(developers)); 
// 'lorence'

const supports = {
    poly: 12,
    mango: 17,
    ajax: 4,
}; 
//console.log(findBestEmployee(supports)); 
// 'mango'

const sellers = {
    lux: 147,
    david: 21,
    kiwi: 19,
    chelsy: 38,
}
//console.log(findBestEmployee(sellers)); 
// 'lux'
```

Comment: Where does it show the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise the variable `bestEmployee` to a known invalid value, best `null`. If you never set it to some employee in the loop, it will remain `null`. So at the end of the function if it is still `null`, return an empty string:

```js
const findBestEmployee = function (employees) {
    'use strict';
  
    let max = 0;
    let bestEmployee = null; // initialise

    for (const employee in employees) {
        const numberOfTasks = employees[employee];
        if (numberOfTasks > max) {
            max = numberOfTasks;
            bestEmployee = employee;
        }
    }

    // return empty string if still null
    return bestEmployee ? bestEmployee : '';
};
```